# Serializing execution of multiple fragments using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, fragment

I'm having an activity with 2 fragments, called A and B. Fragment A has an AsyncTask to parse some data from the internet into an array of custom objects and fill its interface. Fragment B also has to use this array to update its interface. The question is, how can I make sure that Fragment A will finish its job (by finishing the AsyncTask) before the Fragment B show up and use the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: How can I make sure that Fragment A will finish its job (by finishing the AsyncTask)

A: You can set a flag in a sigleton class which can be updated on `onPostExecute` of your asynctask.

Comment: Although there's still some issues but I got the idea. I marked your answer as correct cause you answered first.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use event bus to communication (complex at start but will help you on long-run)

Popular libraries to implement event bus on android

- https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus
- http://square.github.io/otto/ (I use this libarary)

2) You can also use listeners on each fragment that can be attached with activity. Activity can communicate between two fragments.

Comment: The Event Bus seems complicated but I will take a look at it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Async Task then `onPostExecute()` method of `Async` put the code of showing `fragment B`. So that it will ensure that after finishing task of `fragment A` the `fragment B` will show.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

   //Code for fragment A to show data in UI

   // code for showing fragment B
}
```